# Practical example and working of Laplace Smoothing or Linear Interpolation in Natural Language Processing (NLP)

Tags: machine-learning, python, probability, nlp

Let us suppose we have a document where

total_words = 50  (for example -> is,the,now,is,am,here,now)
total_unique_words = 40 (for example -> is,the,am,here,now)

How can we apply the `Linear Interpolation/ Laplace Smoothening` in the case of a `trigram`

for example

('he') has a count of 12
('he', 'is') has a count of 8
('he','is','here') has a count of 4

('is','here') has a count of 6

('is') has a count of 18
('here') has a count of 5

I think it is related to the count of the values. I have the formula in terms of `lambda * P(x_i | x_i-1)` but do not know how to implement here. Can someone please give me an  **PRACTICAL** example of how to implement the interpolation

**Please make any necessary assumptions in the case as I am learning it the first time**